# ¿Por qué no funciona el background-color en <body>?

Tags: html, css

¿Por qué no funciona el background-color en `<body>`?

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb (255, 228, 225);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1365px;
  font-family: century;
  font-size: 20.05px;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.nave li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.nave>li {
  float: left;
}

.nave li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 179, 44);
}

p {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.loren {
  position: absolute;
  top: 227px;
  left: 850px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<title> Triada Primate </title>
```

Debería ser rosa.

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta de abajo con el ejemlo para que lo veas funcionando. Saludos

Comment: Votando por cerrar como "error tipográfico" (ver la respuesta -hay un espacio incorrecto entre el nombre de la función y los paréntesis de `rgb ()`)

Answer (score 4):

Buenas, ponlo así:

```
background-color:rgb(255,228,225);
```

Sin los espacios entre rgb y (

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos!!

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 228, 225);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1365px;
  font-family: century;
  font-size: 20.05px;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.nave li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.nave>li {
  float: left;
}

.nave li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 179, 44);
}

p {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.loren {
  position: absolute;
  top: 227px;
  left: 850px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Background COLOR</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Fondo en rosita rgb</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 por la sutileza de llamarlo "rosita"